# Limit of $f(x) = x \bmod k$

Tags: limits, formal-proofs

I'm trying to prove that a function $f(x)$ tends to infinity when $x$ rises.

Clearly, I used limit to do so.

The problem is, $f(x) = x\ mod\ k$, in which mod is the division's residue of $x$ by $k$.

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} x\ mod\ k\ = \infty$$

Note that $k$ is an arbitrary constant.

I don't know how to express $mod$ in a mathematical way so to prove this.

Can you help me?

Comment: But this is false: $f(x)$ is bounded by $k$. And this function is only defined for $x \in \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: The residue of a division by $k$ is $<k$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please be careful with the tags that you use. Your question is in no way about `formal-proofs`.

Comment: @57Jimmy I think that, by $\mod k$ he means the projection from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}/k\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: @gabriele cassese Ok, sure, this makes sense :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your thesis is wrong:
$f(x+k)=f(x)$ by definition. Thus, since the function is periodic and not constant, the limit you are looking for does not exists

Comment: Indeed, $f(x)$ is periodical so it doesn't tend to infinity.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Work with small examples when one is stuck.

For example, if you let $k$ to be $2$, the relevant sequence would be $f(0)=0,f(1)=1,f(2)=0,f(3)=1,f(4)=0,f(5)=1,\ldots$ 
of which the limit does not exists.